# Send click event and state from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that looks something like this:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import MyAppChild from "./components/my_app_child";
import "./my_app_parent.scss"

const MyAppParent = (props) => {

    function POST(path, data) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:5000${path}`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }
        )
    }

    const [day, setDay] = useState('14');
    const [hour, setHour] = useState('19');
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const onChangeDay = e => {
        setDay(e.target.value)
    }
    
    const onClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        POST('/api', { day: day, hour: hour}).then(
            async (response) => {
                const json = await response.json()
                setData(json.returnData)
            }
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="content-wrapper">
                    <div className="date">
                        <div>
                            <label>Day</label>
                            <input value={day} onChange={onChangeDay} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
                       Get data
                    </button>
                    
                    
                    <div className="my-app-child-wrapper">
                        <MyAppChild
                            day={day}
                            hour={hour}
                            data={data}
                        />
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </>
    )

}

export default MyAppParent;
```

Basically the parent has one input field (`day`). I can fill it out with a number, click the `Get data` button, and the API will return some data (`returnData`) I can then feed to my child component, along with the other values, which then outputs something.

My child component looks something like this:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./my_app_child.scss"

const MyAppChild = (props) => {

    const [hour, setHour] = useState('')

    return (
        <>
            <div className="wrapper">
                {props.data.map((value, i) =>
                    <div key={i} onClick={() => {setHour(i)}}>{value}</div>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    )

}

export default MyAppChild;
```

So the idea here is that the divs that are created from the mapping are clickable. When they are clicked I would like to send the new state of `hour` back to the parent, so that the parent `hour` state is also changed and then run the `const onClick` again to fetch some new data with the new changed state.

But I am not sure how to send the new `hour` state back to the parent and then initiate the API call again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to pass `hour` and `setHour` to your child as props (not just hour), and remove the `useState()` in the child element. Then your onClick will call the parent's function and, update the value causing a re-render, and the child's presentation will be updated.

You have some typo's and other issues in the code snippets above.

Comment: That seemed to semi-work. However, the re-render is not initiated by this. On the parent a button is clicked, but the idea was to re-render when the "buttons" on the child are clicked. So the function in the parent needs to be initiated with clicks in the child as well.